# JavaScript Track click event before following link

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a Javascript snippet which my clients put on their websites. In order to track clicks, I create an XMLHttpRequest, wait for the 200 status and then propagate the click.

Here's the relevant code for the click event:

```
function pingServer(done) {
    var url = "http://www.example.com/api/events/?eventID=" + eventID;
    var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
    invocation.open('GET', url, true);
    invocation.withCredentials = true;
    invocation.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (invocation.readyState == invocation.LOADING && invocation.status == 200) {
            (typeof done === 'function' && done());
        }
    };
    invocation.send(); 
}

// get the href
var href = e.target.href;

// ping then redirect
pingServer(function () { window.location.href = href; });
```

It works perfectly, and I get the ping on my server. The problem is that the delay in waiting for the XMLHttpRequest 200 code is noticeable to the end user. The browser's spinner doesn't start spinning until after that wait. So to the user it's poor UX and it looks like the click didn't do anything.

Is there a more user friendly way of registering a click event while also immediately handling the link redirect?

Comment: No. However, you could replace the clicked item with your own spinner or loading text.

Comment: Other than displaying something, there is not much more you can do t make sure the Ajax call made it to the server.

Comment: Use websockets instead of AJAX, there are designed to be low latency compared to AJAX.

Comment: So OP has to keep a websocket open for a single click?

Comment: I don't know much about what he is working on, but he says that he wants to notify the server for every click done by the user, with low latency. According to this description, it's possible that websockets help him.

Comment: @PierreCapo from what I've read, the decreased latency that comes with web sockets is more for when you're making multiple requests. It can reduce latency for a single message but not by much.